# How to return an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

The question asks:

This method takes the author's name as a String paramter and returns an arraylist of all the books written by that author. It uses a while loop and an interator, locates the books written by that author (case=insensitive) and adds them to another arraylist.

so far I've got:

```
public ArrayList<Book> getBooksByAuthor(String authorName){
   Iterator<Book> it = books.iterator();
   ArrayList books = new ArrayList<String>();
   while(it.hasNext()){
       Book b = it.next();
       if(authorName.equalsIgnoreCase(b.getBookAuthor())){
           books.add(b.getBookTitle());
        }
    }
   return books;
}
```

the question I'm asking is what does the question want me to do exactly? does returning an arraylist mean that you need to recreate those objects? I'm confused on what I'm suppose to do here... Thanks in advance

Comment: Should you be returning an `ArrayList<String>` or an `ArrayList<Book>`? You should choose one not both.

Comment: just replace `b.getBookTitle` with `b` since you want to add the book to the array, and not the `String` that is it's title.

Comment: it should've been <Book> thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your method returns `ArrayList<Book>`.

Your variable is declared as an `ArrayList` rawtype.

Your runtime type is `ArrayList<String>`.

### Make your mind up!!

How about:

```
public List<Book> getBooksByAuthor(String authorName){
    return books.stream()
         .filter(book -> authorName.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getBookAuthor()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```